# Solr full refresh without deleting index

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I want to do solr full refresh with out deleting the index so that the data can be accessed until full refresh is done. Once the full refresh is completed the old index has to be removed. How can i do this, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the use of [multiple cores](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) in your Solr implementation. A "live" core and an "ondeck" core, where "live" is the current index and "ondeck" is the one that you will refresh into. (Note: you can name the cores anything that is meaningful to you) Once the refresh has been completed, you can issue a [SWAP command](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#SWAP) that will switch the two cores out in real time without any impact to the users (eg. Solr will manage the searches being executed against the cores behind the scenes for you).

We have implemented this exact scenario on a couple of other indexes at my current company with very good success.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it helped me lot. But now we are facing problem once we implemented swap. The jvm heap space is increasing automatically and we are getting Java out of memory

Comment: After the swap is complete, I would recommend deleting all items in the old (now "ondeck") index, since that is still a running instance of Solr and would be consuming server resources if it is loaded with items.